# Angular testing with keycloack "user is not logged in"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, keycloak

I have a small application at the moment that uses Keycloak to have a sso. 
However when I want to ng test my main.component.ts I run in to the problem that the standard 'it should create' test fails, I get the following error message:

MainComponent should create
Error: User not logged in

Below is my main.component.spec file

> import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from
>   '@angular/core/testing';
>
> import { MainComponent } from './main.component'; import
>   {AppTopBarComponent} from '../app.topbar.component'; import
>   {AppMenuComponent} from '../app.menu.component'; import {RouterModule}
>   from '@angular/router'; import {RouterTestingModule} from
>   '@angular/router/testing'; import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
>   import {MenuModule} from 'primeng/primeng'; import
>   {AppSubMenuComponent} from '../app.menu.component'; import
>   {KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-angular';
>
> describe('MainComponent', () => {   let component: MainComponent;
>   let fixture: ComponentFixture;
>
> beforeEach(async(() => {
>
> ```
> TestBed.configureTestingModule({
>   declarations: [ MainComponent, AppTopBarComponent, AppMenuComponent, AppSubMenuComponent],
>   providers: [KeycloakService],
>   imports: [RouterModule, RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, MenuModule]
> }).compileComponents();   }));
> ```
>
> beforeEach(() => {
>       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
>       component = fixture.componentInstance;
>       fixture.detectChanges();   }); // TODO: Expects a user to log in but does not happen --> Has something to do with KeyCloak   it('should
>   create', () => {
>       expect(component).toBeTruthy();   });
>
> });

I don't have much experience with testing so I'm not sure how I should approach this? Mock the keycloak somehow?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should mock service:

```
 let Mock1 ={
   someMethod: jasmine.createSpy('someMethod');
  };
```

// in TestBed.configureTestingModule
      providers: [ { provide: KeycloakService, useValu: Mock1 } ]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems to go further now but now I get the folowing error:" TypeError: this.keycloakService.getUsername is not a function "

Comment: did you mock all the methods in service?

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk - can you elaborate? The KeycloakService has 14 methods in it. ALL of them need to be mocked just to get tests to run?

Comment: You should refactor and split big function to smaller ones